# using custom browser with watir-webdriver in Ruby

Tags: browser, selenium, rubygems, webdriver, watir-webdriver

How can Watir be told to use a new or custom web browser, other than the conventional :opera, :ie, :chrome or :firefox?

For example

```
$browser = Watir::Browser.new :firedog
```

What's entailed in modifying the underlying Selenium driver class if, let's say, :firedog is really just a custom build* of Firefox, or Firefox with custom parameters? (*That way I can worry about embedding a webdriver addon into my custom ff separately.)

Hoping to avoid creating a new gem, just extend the required one(s) if possible, but not sure how to do that in the Ruby implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely something you need to ask the folks on the Selenium Webriver list.  I've added the webdriver tag, but I'm not sure how many of them hang out here.

Once a driver is created (similar to chromedriver or operadriver I'd expect) and stuff works with webdriver, then it should work for anything built on top of it such as watir-webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

If you purpose is just custom profiles, adding extensions, you are free to use already implemented API. In case you have custom Firefox build, you still may add WebDriver addon to it and just override binary path to Firefox.

This all is described at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings

Comment: I've seen all that; already been using dedicated profiles with specially tuned settings and extensions (and yes able to switch between multiple ff versions on same server).  Know how I might override command-line parameters Selenium uses to launch Firefox?

Comment: I have at least one idea how to cheat `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path` into using a wrapper around my actual browser: applying Bash trickery to shift away unwanted parameters and add my custom ones, before doing an `exec`. But I can already think of some reasons why that might not work.

Comment: In this case you'll face an old problem when `browser.close` kills not Firefox process, but only bash script which started it.

Comment: A `bash exec` completely replaces the parent with the child and the in-memory script per se ceases to exist, unlike with `fork`. Anyway `browser.close` is the least of my worries, I've had cleanup checks covered pretty well outside watir runs. I've yet to test my wrapper method above--will report back results.